# Wordpress Login and Register pages no body class or id

Tags: wordpress

I need to insert a background image on these two pages:

http://digesale.com/wp-login.php
http://digesale.com/wp-login.php?action=register

You can already see a background there, but I inserted that wrapping a div with another div. But on smaller or larger screen resolutions the background doesn't cover the entire page or has a slider, depending on if it's bigger or smaller resolution.

What I need to do is somehow style the "body" of these two pages with CSS. But the body tag has no class and no id on these pages, and I have no idea how to style it.

For example this page http://digesale.com/privacy-policy/ has this:

body class="page page-id-154 page-template-default

And see how it's nicely styled and everything.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Good job! But please note that your login box does not align in the center.

Comment: Hey Peter. It should be fixed now. I've recently come to find out that different resolutions create different problems that are hard to solve. Can you please check and let me know if the box still doesn't align in the center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work for you:-

```
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'wdm_style', 10 );
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wdm_style' );
    function wdm_style(){
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

               //its check if register page is called or not
                if( (strpos($actual_link, 'wp-login.php') !== false) || (isset($_GET['action']))){ ?>
                     <style>
                         body{
                            background-image: url('your-image-path-here');
                          }
                    </style>
    <?php }

    }
```

Comment: Where should I place this though?

Comment: Functions always in functions.php.

Comment: Okay. I put the code at the very bottom of my functions.php file, right above this piece of code: ?>

However, that didn't work...

Comment: Here's the image I used: http://digesale.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/black-cool-background.jpg

Comment: So that didn't work. Either the code or where I implemented it is the problem. What next?

Comment: But, you see, it still doesn't work on the Login page (it only works on the register page). http://digesale.com/wp-login.php

Comment: Oh, and I forgot about the lost your password page: http://digesale.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword

Can we make it work on the login and lost your password pages too?

Comment: Updated the code, it will work for lostpassword too.

Comment: That did it. Great stuff WisdmLabs. Much appreciated. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Place this at the button of `functions.php` of your theme.

It changes the background image of your wp-login page,

```
add_action("login_head", "my_login_head");
function my_login_head() {
    echo "
    <style>
    body{
        background: url('http://digesale.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/black-cool-background.jpg');        
    }
    </style>
    ";
}
```

This is tested code.

Comment: Hey. Thank you for your effort. I won't try it because WisdmLabs below already solved my problem. But thank you anyway.